# How do I add menthol flavoring to this gum?

Tags: flavor, mint

My boy's birthday is coming next week, and I was thinking of making some homemade. I read the ingredient of gum on the packet and one of them was menthol flavoring.

I'm using this basic recipe:

> Heat the ingredients. Place the gum base, corn syrup, glycerine, citric acid and bubble gum flavoring in the top part of a double boiler. ... Create a powdered sugar well. Pour the gum base into the well. Make bubble gum dough. ... Roll out the dough. Finish the gum.

So, how do I add menthol flavoring to this?

Comment: Important information belongs in the question, not in comments. I edited into the question for you.

Comment: I'm confused here - the recipe tells you when to add the flavoring. If you want menthol flavored gum, what's the problem with adding menthol flavoring instead of bubble gum flavoring?

Comment: i don't know what Should i add Menthol crystal or Powder ?

Answer (score 2):

The recipe already tells you when to add the flavoring. The menthol gives it that minty kick ("cold" feeling) and is used in more than one bubblegum flavoring, like mint, peppermint, sometimes cherry.

For industrial applications it is easier to buy powder and then compound it into the flavor, but for home applications I recommend that you buy a mint flavor solution instead of just straight up adding menthol, since a mint flavor is more than that.